# Alignment of subscripts inside and outside parentheses

Tags: vertical-alignment, subscripts

```
$(X^n_i)_i$
```

This piece of code produces output where the inner i is placed at a lower height than the outer i. Is there a graceful way to place both i's at the same height?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `$\left(X^n_i\right)_i$` will actually place the second index a little lower than the first one, but maybe that is okay for you.

Comment: The same height can be done with `$(X^_i)^{}_i$`.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of closure, here are some examples of what can be done:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
${(X^{n}_{i})}_{i}$ \quad
$\left(X^{n}_{i}\right)_i$ \quad
$(X^{n}_{i})_i$\quad
$(X^n_i)^{}_i$
\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image]